# Bootstrap popover is closing when click inside

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I have a bootstrap popover and its content is a [kendo Ui color picker widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/flatcolorpicker).

When you click in the color picker widget, the popover close even if the `trigger` option is set to `focus`.

Why? How to keep the popover open until a click is made outside the popover?

```
<a id="popover" href="#">Color Picker</a>

var $kendoColorPicker = $("<div></div>").kendoFlatColorPicker({
    value: "#ffffff"
});

$("#popover").popover({
    container: "body", 
    content: $kendoColorPicker, 
    html: true, 
    placement: "bottom", 
    trigger: "focus"
});
```

See a live demo here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqp16ad7/3/)

Comment: Just remove `trigger: "focus"` . [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqp16ad7/4/)

Comment: No, because I want the popover to close automatically when you click outside

Comment: Use outsideClick="true". This will only close the popover by clicking outside of popover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly simplified and generalized version of [user1119279's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972423/1036728):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({trigger: "click"}).click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

  }).on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
    $(".popover").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    })
  })

  $(document).click(function () {
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide')
  })
})
```

This version also preserves the behaviour where clicking multiple times on the trigger button toggles the popover.

Comment: Super clean and mitigates all the jumpyness and random sticky popovers from other answers.

Comment: This will disable any required click on popover like a button inside it.

Answer (score 5):

A different approch:

```
function getContent() {
  console.log("getContent");
  return $("<div></div>")
    .kendoFlatColorPicker({
    value: "#ffffff"
  }).click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}

$("#popover").popover({
    container: "body",
    content: getContent,
    html: true,
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "manual"}
).click(function(event) {
  $("#popover").popover('show')
  event.stopPropagation();
})

$(document).click(function() {
  $("#popover").popover('hide')
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqp16ad7/6/)

but for some reason the slider does not work

I think you should use an alternative solution (for example "spectrum")

Answer (score 3):

The best and native solution I found is using `trigger="manual"` and handle the `blur` event.

Here is the code:

```
$("#popover").popover({
  content: '<button>Click Me And Not Close The Popup</button>',
  html: true,
  trigger: "manual",
  // other options
}).on('blur', function(ev) { // keep shown when focus on child of popover
  if (!$(ev.relatedTarget).parent().is('#popover')) {
    $('#popover').popover('hide');
  }
  // if you have multiple inputs in popover that can be focused, use
  // $(ev.relatedTarget).one('blur', callback)
  // to make popover hide after it blur
}).on('click', function() {
  $('#popover').popover('toggle');
  // or always show: $('#popover').popover('show')
})
```

In this example, `document` will not be used and only handle events on the element directly!

Comment: This was a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try by removing trigger:"focus" and apply some custom code

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".popover");

    if (!container.is(e.target)  && container.has(e.target).length === 0)  {
        container.popover("hide");
    }
 })
```